# Nvidia-prime not working | AMD + Nvidia | XMG-Core 4800H+RTX2060

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, amd-graphics, nvidia-optimus

I bought new Laptop and installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it. It is an XMG Core 15 with an 4800H and 2060. I have some Problems with the Prime integrated. The external ports are only wired to the nvidia card and the internal screen is only wired to the iGPU. I am using the preinstalled `gdm3`.

After the fresh install of Ubuntu I installed the newest nvidia-driver450. `nvidia-settings` is working and so is `prime-select`. So here are the Problems:

1. When running `nvidia-settings` there is listed

   ```
   Message: 10:15:53.707: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort 
   Message: 10:15:53.707: PRIME: is it supported? no
   ```

Thus I can not choose a prime profile. I also can not use prime-run for rendering jobs or benchmarks `prime-run: command not found`. They are always running on the amdgpu. Prime-run is installed. CUDA jobs are working and running on the Nvidia-gpu.

2. I cannot extend the desktop to an external display. `Nvidia-settings` lists it but does not show me the tool to configure monitors. The ubuntu settings does not detect the external display. Changing the `xorg.conf` did not help. I tried various configurations. This is the one I am using at the moment.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "amd"
    Screen 1 "nvidia"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "amd"
    Driver "amdgpu"
    BusID "PCI:05:00:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amd"
    Device "amd"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:05:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
EndSection
```

Below is the output of `glxinfo -B`. Is it correct the device using `llvmpipe`? Shouldnt it be using `amdgpu`?

[llvmpipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTivu.jpg)

As I nearly always have an charger available. An acceptable workaround would be using just the nvidia card.

Thank you for your help. I am happy to provide more information if wanted.

**Edit:**
The xorg.conf below gave me working external displays. The internal is not responding and just showing the manufacturer logo.

```
Section "Module"
    Load "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:01:00:0"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it.
Apperently the 4800h is to new for kernel 5.4. **I updated to kernel 5.8.1** in the following the displays got recognized but **stayed black**.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

I then followed the description of the following post in the nvidia forums. *(Read carefully, there are 2 methods described in this one post)*.

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-xconfig-doesnt-do-what-i-want-it-to-nor-does-nvidia-settings/107883/7

Now external displays and internal displays are **working**.

Delete the xorg.conf. You do not need it and you will not get an working solution with it.

1. In  /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf replace `Driver "amdgpu"` with `Driver "modesetting"`
2. Then add `Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"` to  `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf`
3. Create the two files named `optimus.desktop` in `/etc/xdg/autostart/` and `/usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart/` with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Optimus
Exec=sh -c "xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0; xrandr --auto"
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=DisplayServer
```

This is very important. These files will be executed with startup.

Comment: For anybody who has done this. Updating your nvidia driver resets /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf. You have to modify this file again.

Comment: Hi! Which one has you used? I've tryied both without success (replace 10-amd and 10-nvidia; and then only create the xorg.conf). I have an Asus TUF 506iv.

Comment: @IgnacioD.Favro I edited the post above and described every step I did. Please delete `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. I guess you forgot Step 3. Please make sure you created these two files. Else your external monitors will not be started up.

Comment: Thank you @Oxyged, but I did everithing as you mention in your comment but it doesn't work, I've also updated the kernel with the mainline distribution, but well, I'll continue trying.

Comment: @IgnacioD.Favro I actually tried to install Ubuntu18.04 on a similiar machine and got the same Problem. It may be a Problem with the kernel > 5.9. To which kernel did you update?